# Clarification on a question involving ratios

Tags: reference-request, ratio

I have the following question in a past paper.  I think I answered it correctly but am not sure and would appreciate someone to let me know if it is indeed correct:

Mrs. Alishaw owns many books on a number of subjects.  The ratio of Maths books to History books is 4:11.  The ratio of Maths and Physics books combined to History books is 7:13.  What is the minimum number of books that Mrs Alishaw owns?

This is what I did:

Since the number of history books will remain the same, it must have been simplified to 11 in one case and 13 in the other (unless she has a fraction of a book, which is unlikely) as they are both prime numbers.  Thus, I found the lowest common multiple (143) and added that to the number of Maths and Physics Books combined (multiplied by 11, 143/13, to fit the ratio), 77, to get 220.

Thank you in advance for your help

Sent from a new poster (n00b)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

The key is indeed assuming integer values for $m$, $h$, and $p$, and working from the divisibility relations that come out of the ratios you are given:

$4 \mid (11m) \implies 4 \mid m$

$7 \mid (13(m+p)) \implies 7 \mid (m+p)$

$11 \mid (4h) \implies 11 \mid h$

$13 \mid (7h) \implies 13 \mid h$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Sorry I can't vote up as I don't have enough rep